# Flatpak and Sideload possible serious bug

Tags: flatpak, sudo, sideload

Just wanted to post that in my experience with Sideload and flatpakref files, I am not being asked to escalate privileges in order to install.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, answering this rather than deleting it, just in case any other users get this confused like I did.

Escalation is not necessary because this is installing apps as the user.